ag-grid-react server side pagination begin range is?
i try to "translate" my ag-grid component from vue3 to react,
when in vue the pagination works perfect in react i get in the second range a "?"
such as in the screenshot below.
the datasource i set in function onGridReady, and in the getRows property i declare the pageNumber, url with search params, fetch the data and invoke the params.success method with the rows and the total rows
  const onGridReady = useCallback((params) => {
        setGridApi(params.api);
        const datasource = {
            getRows: async (params) => {

                const pageNumber = (Math.floor(params.request.startRow / pageSize) + 1).toString();

                console.log("Grid state: ", params.request)//[![request][1]][1]

                const url = new URL(`${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL}/api/${table}`);
                url.searchParams.append('page', pageNumber);
   
                await fetch(url)
                    .then(resp => resp.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log("data ", data) // [![data object][1]][1]
                        params.success({rowData: data.data, rowCount:data.meta.total})
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
                        params.fail();
                    });
            },
        };

        params.api.setGridOption('serverSideDatasource', datasource);

    }, [])


